# Do file extensions matter if you're sending the right MIME type?

Tags: http, video, mime

I vaguely recall reading that for some audio and video file types, some browsers check not only the HTTP `Content-Type` header but also the file extension in the URL. Is that so? And what would happen if I output, for example, an MP4 video with the correct `Content-Type: video/mp4` HTTP header but an unusual file extension (or no file extension at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Quicktime is shocking at reading MIME types and relying on extensions. The older versions seemed to be OK. [You can read my troubles about it here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/embedding-quicktime-player-behaves-differently-on-xp-osx-windows7).

I've also seen FireFox do strange things when your MIME type and extension are different. For example, downloading a `jpg` with `Content-Disposition=attachment` without setting a MIME type it went and put a `.html` extension on the end of the file after it had finished downloading.